# Hidden elements are not loaded properly after being displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tabbed toggle statistic page, which has 10 separate tabs that include charts. By clicking each tab, preloaded corresponding chart is being showed up. However, it does not scale into its container. More weird thing is, when I resize the window, visible chart is shown properly (I suppose it does some recalculation thingy). How should I modify my code so that it does that recalculation thingy after a click, or any suggestions on the problem?

Here is my jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/g66ut7c6/

```
<!--BEGIN TABS-->
               <div class="tabbable tabbable-custom">
                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                     <li>
                        <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab">
                        1
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab">
                        2
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab">
                        3
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="tab-content">
                     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_1">
                        <div class="scroller">
                           <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                              <div class="portlet light">
                                 <p> Piechart by ülkeler </p>

                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_2">
                        <div class="scroller">
                           <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                              <div class="portlet light">
                                 <p> Piechart by step dağılımı </p>

                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_3">
                        <div class="scroller">
                           <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                              <div class="portlet light">
                                 <p> Piechart by hasta sayısı ay </p>

                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!--END TABS-->
```

Before resize [image: Before resize]

After a resize, the size is okay
[image]

I could not include charts in my jsfiddle because they contain some ruby code.

PS: Using Chartkick and Google Charts to draw charts, and MetronicJS for tabs.

Edit: The first chart that is visible by default is being display properly initially, however others are not. After a resize of a window when another chart is visible, the previous one gets broken again.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically fire the 'resize' event:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Just attach it to the 'click' event that shows the tab.

In your case:

```
$('div.tabbable > ul > li > a').click( function() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
```

If your component doesn't resize as respond to the event, you could actually resize the window with:

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

**UPDATE**:

If it is not posible to resize the window (see comments) you could try to redraw the chart when the tab becomes visible. Maybe in that way the chart is able to calculate properly the dimensions it needs to fit in. Something like:

```
$( 'div.tabbable > ul > li > a' ).click( function() {
    myChart.draw( myData );
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it is no use. I can not even get to resize the window in chrome, I suppose it is not supported by some browsers such as Chrome, Firefox etc. so resizing can not be fired programatically.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Burak, I was reading now in MDN about it and it is true that there are [restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo). Actually I coundn't make it work on the OP's fiddle. I could dispatch the event with `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))` though, but I am not sure when it will make the chart to resize as well.

Comment: I do not know why doesn't it resize the charts, it looks like it has no effects on them at all.  Thanks for the replies btw ^_^

Comment: And what about to draw them when you click on the tab instead of when the page load?  I don't know if you have seen the updated answer.